# How to solve this Go cyclical dependency

Tags: go

I've been learning Go for a class course and I am very excited with the language, it really is very useful for web services.

So, I've been writing this CRUD restful API for a final project and I keep running in  the damn circular dependency problem. I've already researched and read on the ways of solving it and will post here just for the sake of it, but first the problem I am having:

*routes* need to know about the handler functions in the *handlers* package, which in turn need to know about the *user* structure inside the *model* package, which in order to send a registration e-mail with a link need to know about the *routes* path

Classical A -> B -> C -> A

Now, I am trying to write this API using MVC and three layer architecture, this I would love for my routes to be in a controller package, my handlers to be on a business logic package and my user on a model package. This is also needed because I have over 43 model classes, I need them tidy up and tucked away on their package.

Ok, the solutions I found out

1 - **Throw everybody on the same package** : That's what I've been doing so far but is a very horrible solution for obvious reasons.

2- **Pass whatever *user* needs as argument when it's functions are called**: That would be a good solution, but won't work because the function that is being called from *user* is from an interface implementation because it has to be a generic call and before anyone goes around saying that my problem is because I am forcing generics in go, well too bad, I need that generic, I will not write over 160 crud functions. The whole point of functions is to avoid code repetition.

3- **Create another package, with another interface, and have it having a instance of handlers and user and have it pass arguments from one to the other**: Despite the reason mentioned above, the need of generic, this sounds like an unnecessarily complicated solution, I refuse to believe that this is better design than circular dependencies.

Bottom line question: How to solve this dependency when C needs to know information from A and generics must be respected

I can post some code here if you need to but I don't see the relevance of specific code when this is more of a high level question.

**EDIT**: Solved my dependency problem. Thank you all for the comments and answer as it led me to the answer. I don't think I've implemented any of the solutions suggested but it did taught me a lot about how to solve the problem, and they would all be very acceptable and doable solution if it wasn't for my own constrains where I don't want to pass anything to User.
To anyone trying to solve their own dependency problem, what I was able to gather is, instead of making in my case, C ask something from A, give to C whatever it needs, before it has to ask, meaning pass the information to him.

Alas, that was not my solution, what I did was remove the information from A and give the information to Z, now both A and C are asking the path information to Z, which is just a Map, sitting there being all map like and holding information.
Thank you all

Comment: Is `A` or `C` supposed to be the "top-level" package here? Even though you don't have a "main" package, you need to think of the top level conceptually the same way as "main", nothing else can import it.

Comment: Wild guess: User doesn't (and probably shouldn't) need to know about routes. It only needs some URL, which is a string. Pass that down from the handler. Alternatively, have User depend on some interface, which is defined in model and implemented elsewhere. That being said, you are discovering that organizing things by type ( models, handlers, etc.) is silly. Organize by domain instead (package user, package blog, etc.). And if the project is small, a single package is totally okay too.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the tip, I will try to re imagine the solution with that in mind, I confess I never thought about it since its a server. I guess the main would be the routes package since they are the ones capturing the http requests.

Comment: @peter I can't pass the url down, that would be the best solution I guess( point #2 explains why I can't pass it down). I see what you are saying, Instead of having routes, for example, centralized in a package, each model  would know about the routes that deal with them. It sounds like a very interesting approach... I will explore that further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got some options, and you've found some of them. The main ways of handling this are:

- Refactor your design to turn the cycle into a tree. This doesn't really apply to your situation due to your requirements.
- Refactor your design to use some kind of dependency injection (this is your 2nd option in your question). This is perfectly viable, and probably the cleanest and easiest.
- Refactor your design to take a *locally declared* interface. This is a more Go-idiomatic version of your option 3. Because interfaces in Go are duck-typed, you get to define it where it's consumed, rather than where it's implemented. So your user package can define a one-method interface for "a thing that gives me a URL I need" and it never needs to reference the package that implements the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I really don't quite understand your 2nd and 3rd point. Both kinda that look like the same thing, having an interface that will pass the required info. Even if the interface is locally declared on users, whoever implements it has to pass that to the user function that needs the url, how can I have someone passing something when i trying to keep the functions that lead to the user;s function call generic? I think my explanation was a little confusing, I can post the code in case you want to.

Comment: I didn't say anything about an interface in the second option. Just that your function can *receive* what it needs, rather than *going and getting* what it needs.

Comment: I've read on dependency injection and now I see the difference between the two option but is there a way to inject the dependency without having to pass in on the function call? The function is part of a interface that is being used to simulate generics, so Im not passing any arguments in it. For the third option, how can whoever implement the interface provide User with the information, save by passing as argument

Comment: User will have to take something as a parameter. That's how you avoid unnecessary dependencies and circular dependencies.